# Keep my ssh being unlocked once it is unlocked

Tags: ssh, 21.10, plasma

I don't want to enter my ssh key's password every time. However, common methods are not my case:

- `ssh-add`: I don't want to run a separated command
- key without a passphrase: ABSOLUTELY NOT!
- Store in a keychain: I don't want it to be auto unlocked

I expect that the key will remain unlocked once I unlocked it at any place.

I know that GNOME did that by using some unknown black magic, so how to do that on KDE plasma?

EDIT: That not 20.10, 21.10 instead LOL...

EDIT: I repeated 20.10 twice...

EDIT: The original title stinks...

Comment: I jave a 'ssh-prime' command on my workstation I run this once per boot to load in the ssh-key.    Then when I login to any of my local server nodes no pass-phrases.

The private keys only exists on my workstation and the public key is on all the user accounts and nodes need access to.

Comment: There is no Black Magic in Gnome it is software not some kind of spell. this kind of comment does not help.

Comment: I know there are no "black magic", as I am also a programmer. That's a simile.